# Search API + Views

Tags: 7, views, search

How can I retrieve fields from other entities using relationships to an indexed node in a View?

As an example... if I create a relationship using "Indexed Node: Author".  And then try to display the Author's name in my search results view, the name is empty.  I've tried every combination of relationship and field from the selectors, but the name is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone else... Upgrading to the latest dev version of the Entity API (currently 7.x-1.3+4-dev) made this work as expected.

My related entity's fields appeared in the view as soon as I upgraded the module.